# Simple Express.js backend working with hard coded data, swapping to use JSON-file

Tags: javascript, express, backend

I'm building a simple backend with Express. Everything works fine. But I have the sample data array (bears) hard coded in the server.js-file. I have transformed the bears data into a external JSON-file. What would be the best practice to get the same bears-array from this JSON-file.

I know I can use **import JSONdata from "./data/DataOfBears.json";** at the top. But how to replace the const bears =[] -section?

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.get("/api/bears", (req, res) => {
  const bears = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Kodiak bear",
      nameLatin: "Ursus arctos middendorffi",
      description:
        "The Kodiak bear (Ursus arctos middendorffi), also known as the Kodiak brown bear, sometimes the Alaskan brown bear, inhabits the islands of the Kodiak Archipelago in southwest Alaska",
      kingdom: "Animalia",
      image:
        "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/bear-isolated-on-white-background-picture-id500565090?k=6&m=500565090&s=612x612&w=0&h=AYpiv8hOMO63fcBoitA-YrFM_V7pBNQKErxsZP-8KkM="
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Cinnamon bear",
      nameLatin: "Ursus americanus cinnamomum",
      description:
        "The cinnamon bear (Ursus americanus cinnamomum) is both a color phase and subspecies of the American black bear, native to central and western areas of the United States and Canada",
      kingdom: "Animalia",
      image:
        "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/bear-isolated-on-white-background-picture-id500565090?k=6&m=500565090&s=612x612&w=0&h=AYpiv8hOMO63fcBoitA-YrFM_V7pBNQKErxsZP-8KkM="
    }
  ];
  res.json(bears);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started, port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse and pass JSON file directly via express

```
const data = require('/path/to/data.json')     
app.get("/api/bears", function (req, res) {
     res.json(data);
})
```